# Regarding SFMC default Update profile option in email templates

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template

we have custom update profile option and wanted to take out the default provided by marketing cloud in email templates.

what are the consequences if we remove default update profile which SFMC provides or do we have any workaround for this.[image: Update profile]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You an manage the default headers and footers in **Admin** > **Account Settings** > **Edit**.

There are some validation checks in place to ensure you're including the proper footer links for CAN-SPAM compliance.

SFMC Support can help you if you'd like to redefine the Profile Center  (`%%profile_center_url%%`), Subscription Center (`%%subscription_center_url%%`) and One-Click Unsubscribe (`%%unsub_center_url%%`) [**personalization strings**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/).

Comment: Nice - didn't know that support could change this. If you are managing your preferences outside the marketing cloud or use custom footers / unsub links, you can get support to deactivate the validations that Adam mentions.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a custom footer and added these script lines

```
%%[/*
This is to bypass a security check related  to those parameters
*/]%%
%%[ IF 0 == 1 THEN ]%%
%%profile_center_url%%
%%unsub_center_url%%
%%Member_Busname%%
%%Member_Addr%%
%%Member_City%%
%%Member_State%%
%%Member_PostalCode%%
%%Member_Country%%
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

I do that because I'm pretty sure I'm using the required information on my emails. These are not commercial ones, only transnationals.

Once I republish and restart the Triggered Sends I got the footer removed.